How is Cittamatra practiced in the Gelug school?
I'm new to studying Tibetan Buddhism. I'd like to ask how the Cittamatra doctrine is practiced in the Gelug school. I'm not referring to the hierarchy this school establishes of Yogacara as a preliminary step to studying Madhyamika Prasangika, but rather if some of the analyses presupposed by Cittamatra are practiced yogically; is it done this way, or is it more of a scholarly, theoretical study, to then assimilate it into a larger framework within Madhyamika?
Thank you for your help.
